Copy only new files from SFTP to UNC path
I need to copy only new files from SFTP location to a UNC path. To identify new files, I copied the files to a Processed folder in SFTP after copying to UNC path is done.
Issue with this approach is if the copy to Processed folder fails, how to make sure that file is not copied again to UNC path.


To identify new files, I copied ...

It sounds like you're unhappy with this means of identifying new files,
given that such a copy operation can fail.
Ideally you would periodically run a report locally on the server
which records in a manifest file a few vital details:
filename, size, mtime, SHA3 hash.
Then it's a matter of syncing up manifests.
To make your current approach work better,
I recommend that instead of copying to the Processed/ folder,
you instead rename each file into that folder.
It's an atomic operation, not likely to fail due to e.g. disk full.
Then each file is present in exactly one location on the SFTP server,
and clients can easily ignore already-processed files.
While we're on that topic, I strongly recommend that you
use rsync to accomplish the nitty gritty work of copying the bits.
It's very efficient if you accidentally ask it to copy same
file multiple times.
And there's essentially no risk of folks encountering a
partial corrupted file.
It (roughly) copies from ReadMe to .123ReadMe,
and only does an atomic rename to proper filename
after a successful transfer.
So in the event of disk full or network timeout,
the worst that will happen is it leaves the occasional
hidden dotfile lying around, which won't be confused for
"the real thing".
